# Sum of even-numbered Fibonacci terms is wrong

Tags: java

I'm learning programming with Java. This is my solution to [the second problem in Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) which seems to give the right answer, however, I'm sure it's buggy.

The problem is if I change the MAX_TERM_VALUE to 100, I get the answer 188. By calculating the answer by hand, I'm expecting 44. It seems that the program loops one to many times but I can't work out how to stop it doing this.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fibA = 0;
    int fibB = 1;
    int fibC = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while (fibC < MAX_TERM_VALUE) {
        fibC = fibA + fibB;
        fibA = fibB;
        fibB = fibC;

        if (fibC %2 == 0) {
            total = total + fibC;
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(total);  
}
private static final int MAX_TERM_VALUE = 4000000;
```

Comment: What is project-euler problem #2? Based on the code sample, it looks like it has something to do with finding the total of all even fibonnaci numbers less than a certain value?

Comment: It is finding the sum of all even numbers in the fibonacci sequence under 4 mio.

Comment: Sorry, it's from the projecteuler.net website. Specifically, the problem is "By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for error is that you only check that a number is valid after summing up, thus you also get 134 as it first gets over MAX_TERM_VALUE the next iteration.

Look:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fibA = 0;
    int fibB = 1;
    int fibC = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while (fibC < MAX_TERM_VALUE) { //fibC is 89 and under MAX_TERM_VALUE = 100
        fibC = fibA + fibB; //fibC is 144 and more than MAX_TERM_VALUE 
        fibA = fibB;
        fibB = fibC;

        if (fibC %2 == 0) {
            total = total + fibC; //The fibC is added anyway as the check only happens next iteration
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(total);  
}
private static final int MAX_TERM_VALUE = 4000000;
```

You should do the following instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fibA = 0;
    int fibB = 1;
    int fibC = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while (true) { 
        fibC = fibA + fibB;  
        fibA = fibB;
        fibB = fibC;
        if (fibC >= MAX_TERM_VALUE){
             break;
        }
        if (fibC %2 == 0) {
            total = total + fibC; 
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(total);  
}

private static final int MAX_TERM_VALUE = 4000000;
```

Which should work as the check is done before summing up.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you YAG. Is this a neat way of doing it or is there a much cleaner way?

Comment: Some minor comments:

1. You, following the original, use more temporary variables than necessary.

2. Every 3rd Fibonacci number is even (easy proof).

3. More info at: http://oeis.org/A014445

2.

Answer (score 0):

After calculating the answer by hand try running your program in a debugger and stepping through every statement for the 100 limit, watching the variables. You'll eventually see it add 144 to total and hopefully be able to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Xan, but I don't know how to use a debugger yet. Anyway, I sort of knew what the error was and why it happened, I was more interested in how to correct it.

Comment: @Atyeo, try using a debugger next time you don't understand what's happening. It can be enlightening to watch you program execute one line at a time.